# AccessDeniedException when trying to open Code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I'm a new AWS user. I'm just logged in and went to the code pipeline in my AWS console, but right off the bat, I'm getting this error on my screen:

```
AccessDeniedException
User: arn:aws:iam::1122067780:user/friendlydev is not authorized to perform: codepipeline:ListPipelines on resource: arn:aws:codepipeline:ap-northeast-1:1221247882:* because no identity-based policy allows the codepipeline:ListPipelines action
```

Can someone help me with this? I haven't even done anything yet.

Comment: You will need to get your AWS admin to add the relevant permissions for your IAM. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/permissions-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by following the tutorial on this [website](https://weonlymeetondreams.blogspot.com/2022/09/fixing-accessdeniedexception-user-is.html).
Basically I just added the `codepipeline:ListPipelines` permission as stated there.